What ever happened to combinatorial chemistry? (Super hyped in the 90s.)
I remember a lot of hype about combintorial chemistry in the late 90s, to include pharma and electronic applications.  It seemed like everything was going to move to synthesis on chips and the like.  But then...if I look at current ACS journals, it's not like they are full of "did it on an array chip" synthesis.  I'm sure there are some papers if I look hard enough.  But just a quick look in JACS or specialty journals below that, and most of the new molecule/material papers look extremely traditional, still.  So...what happened?
P.s.  I remember quantum computing was also going to be big...and then sort of dwindled and came back recently (but still seems deep in "hope for the future" world).  I guess "AI" has sort of had waves of faddiness also.  I remember it being a hot topic in the late 80s and then dwindling...and LISP was even 20 years before that.  And now it is hot again (writing "algo content" essays).  So maybe combinatorial chemistry will come back eventually and put all the traditional lab beaker users out of business?

Once a technique is developed, academic research labs are less likely to mention it in a title or abstract of a publication. The technique gets adopted by industrial labs (big pharma, contract labs) but they have little need to publish.
If you want to get an update on innovations related to combinatorial chemistry, here is one paper you could start with. They are using multiple starting molecules, claiming that they get a better diversity of molecules compared to classic combinatorial chemistry.

So...what happened?

Science makes progress and switches focus on some new shiny idea, while continuing to use the powerful ideas that folks came up with ten (or hundred) years earlier.
Working at the smallest possible scale will remain important to reduce costs for starting materials and costs of hazardous waste treatment. Many routine operations have transitioned to highly parallel operation using 96-well plates (or more miniature devices) at smaller scale. And many novel techniques (like second generation DNA sequencing) rely on high throughput achieved by immobilizing reagents or samples on a tiny part of a surface.
Just because the keyword "combinatorial chemistry" is not as popular anymore does not mean that the technical advances and the ideas behind them have been rejected.

Thanks much for the response! 1.  Still does seem like the technique has not been as relevant to new synthesis as touted.  And I somewhat disagree on "methods" not being disclosed om ACS papers.  They may not be explained in detail, but certainly are at a medium level, which is enough to tell if traditional methods were used or not.  2.  Also, I differentiate screening/analytical techniques from array synthesis of new molecules, materials.  3.  Still think there is more to the "story" of how this stuff was hyped and then didn't fulfil hype.
